# Strange NodeJS websocket based app crash when running idle for a long time

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, ubuntu, websocket

I have a puzzeling issue with a small nodejs app, that runs as a backend for a multiplayer card-playing web-app.
It runs on Ubuntu server 22.04. Nodejs is version 16.17.0 LTS.
It uses the built-in modules https and fs and besides that it uses websockets WS-module version 8.8.1
And it runs as an unprivileged user.
Basically the backend sends messages back and forth between the online-card-players using websocket-connections. This works just fine, people are playing for hours, and there seems to no problems with it.
The issue is:
If the backend runs idle for a long time, maybe 3-4 hours, THEN it seems to crash when a connection request comes in.
The only info I have is an entry in the servers /var/log/apport.log that says

ERROR: apport (pid 3093) Thu Aug 18 08:10:21 2022: called for pid 847, signal 6, core limit 0, dump mode 1

ERROR: apport (pid 3093) Thu Aug 18 08:10:21 2022: executable: /usr/bin/node (command line "node /home/cardbackend/websocket/start")

ERROR: apport (pid 3093) Thu Aug 18 08:10:21 2022: is_closing_session(): no DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in environment

I do not have a lot of experience with nodejs, but maybe some of you have an idea about what the cause of this is.
My guess is that it maybe has something to do with environment-variables or something like that.

Any Nodejs wizards out there?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a SIGABT is being raised

ERROR: apport (pid 3093) Thu Aug 18 08:10:21 2022: called for pid 847, **signal 6**, core limit 0, dump mode 1

A lot of things can cause a signal 6/SIGABT but given the long running nature of the app I would start looking at resources such as disk space, memory, cpu  also by checking if there is any additional info in the OS logs.